# How to use or get hold of Microsoft Entity Framework data models in native c++?

Tags: entity-framework

Is there anyway we can use EntityFrameWork data models in native C++? Is there any recommended best practices? I have searched and found

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6efba6fd-fff7-44f6-8501-6b856186b9ea/is-allow-to-use-the-entity-framework-in-unmanaged-code-as-com?forum=adodotnetentityframework

http://forums.oreilly.com/topic/17339-use-of-entity-framework-with-visual-c/page__p__29926#entry29926

Any example code samples or references for more examples will be of great help.

Comment: You will have to interop with an existing C# library (assuming C++/CLI does not support expressions) with C++/CLI.

Comment: Hi leppie, Thanks. I will follow the approach.